# Syntax error while running mongo-connector between MongoDB and Neo4J

Tags: python, mongodb, neo4j

I am using `mongo-connector` to do the initial `bulk_upsert` operation between MongoDB and Neo4J. At some point while querying with py2neo, the `InvalidSyntax` exception is occurring due to which nothing is being inserted into graph database. I believe the issue lies somewhere in the `DocManager` during syntax translations. I am running `py2neo v2.0.8` and `Neo4J v2.3.1`.
Here is the detailed stack trace:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 85, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 256, in run
    docman.upsert(doc, ns, timestamp)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/neo4j_doc_manager.py", line 66, in upsert
    tx.commit()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 333, in commit
    return self.post(self.__commit or self.__begin_commit)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 288, in post
    raise self.error_class.hydrate(error)
InvalidSyntax: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace, comment or a label name (line 1, column 20 (offset: 19))
"MERGE (d:Document: { _id: {parameters}._id})"
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: Please post the related code, especially the part with the `MERGE` line!

Comment: Klaus, I don't think that would help.`mongo-connector` is an open source project and I assure you I've dug into the code and this is more of a workflow problem than a programming error. I posted here on SO because I've seen some people from the `neo4j_doc_manager` dev community and thought they could help.

Comment: It looks strange that the `MERGE` has a colon *after* `Document`. Does the collection in Mongo have the colon at the end?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster, No it doesn't. Hmm, interesting observation... this shouldn't be happening. I'm pretty new to Neo4J so not sure why this could be happening. Maybe you can follow the conversation at this [issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager/issues/56) I've reported to see if this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this.

Neo4j Doc Manager uses a key naming convention of `xxx_id` to identify relationships, where the value of a property with key `xxx_id` is assumed to be an id referencing a document in collection `xxx`. This convention allows us to define relationships from the document data model. I'm assuming that the error here is caused by Neo4j Doc Manager treating the nested document's `_id` field as a relationship, but not checking for a null collection name (since nothing appears before "_id" in the key).

This is a bug and we'll add a check for this to avoid the Cypher syntax error. Those interested can track the issue here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager/issues/56

Comment: Yes, that would be the issue that I opened :)